# For Loops Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, code-conversion

I'm trying to convert this code from Javascript to CoffeeScript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    str += "Hello" + names[i] + "!<br />";
}
```

But at the CoffeeScript project home page there is only a simple example of how to do `for` loops and I can't understand it quite well too, so how can I make convert that to CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
str += 'Hello' + name + '!<br />' for name in names
```

Comment: I think CoffeeScript has built in string interpolation, so you should also be able to do `str += "Hello ${name}!<br />" ...`

Comment: @CD That's a neat feature `:)` @Nathan Does this string interpolation thing work for you? If yes, I'll put it in my answer....

Comment: Nope, the result was `Hello ${name}!<br />Hello ${name}!<br />Hello ${name}!<br />`

Comment: @Nathan Try this: `str += "Hello #{name}!<br />"`. This [article](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/strings/interpolation) suggests that the `#` sign is used for string interpolation, not the `$` sign...

Comment: Using `#` I got this: `Hello Nathan,John,Michel!<br />`

Comment: Oh yes, it's `#{<expr>}`. I got confused with the jQuery Templates format, sorry!

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

`msg = ("Hello #{name}!" for name in names).join '\n'`

Answer (score 1):

Šime and Acorn beat me to the best answers, but it's worth adding that the literal translation of your code would be

```
for i in [0...names.length]
  str += "Hello #{names[i]}!<br />"
```

or using postfix rather than indentation,

```
str += "Hello #{names[i]}!<br />" for i in [0...names.length]
```